# JMETER Test Script Recorder greys off

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter 5.3. I had selected Templates > Recording, filled the following details and click on Create.
[Templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLz7B.png)

As per the screenshot, the Test Script Recorder is greyed-off:
[Test Recorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjtmL.png)

I had imported the certificates to the IE too.
[Certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq454.png)

Could someone advise what could have gone wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this: Right Click on the Recorder and click on Enable. Did not know there is additional step in the new version!

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's greyed it is usable.

You should not enable it as it will make the View Results Tree under Test Script Recorder receive Sample Results from replay instead of keeping only recording.

It's not a change in 5.3, it is just more noticeable with the new LAF.

Comment: Hi, I tried to record when it is grey. If the results tree is not active, then it will be hard to know if the recording works fine.

Comment: The result tree will be active but only for recording

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, don't be confused, it works normally:

[image]

Also I would recommend reconsidering using Internet Explorer, when you change its proxy settings it amends system-wide proxy configuration, the same applies to certificates storage. To keep your system clean it's better to use the browser which has separate proxy/certificates configuration like [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/). If you need to mimic IE or any other browser it will be enough to send the relevant [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) string via [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

Also be aware of alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: Hi,  Thank you for the recording and the explanations. It is definitely helpful for newbie like me! :)